# returning page state as JSON

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Instead of returning the current page as `return this.Page()`, i need to return it as JSON with return url - something like that `return new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = Url.Page(this.Page()) });`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it - `return new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = this.Url })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  return Json(new {redirectUrl = this.Url});
```